# Gst.init fails under anaconda, but works with native python

Tags: python, anaconda, gstreamer

Initialisation of *Gst* works under python as installed by ubuntu, not with python installed by anaconda:

I wrote a small script to show what happens:

```
$ cat gstinit.py 
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst
Gst.init(None)
print("Done!")
```

Here is the result using ubuntu python:

```
$ /usr/bin/python2.7 gstinit.py 
Done!
```

But simply using `python` as installed by anaconda gives:

```
$ python gstinit.py 

** (process:27029): WARNING **: Failed to load shared library 'libgstreamer-1.0.so.0' referenced by the typelib: libiconv.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gstinit.py", line 4, in <module>
    Gst.init(None)
gi._error.GError: g-invoke-error-quark: Could not locate gst_init: libiconv.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (1)
```

A search for the failed library succeeds:

```
$ ls -lt $(find /usr -name libgstreamer-1.0.so.0)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 sept.  6 15:16 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 -> libgstreamer-1.0.so.0.803.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 sept.  6 15:12 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 -> libgstreamer-1.0.so.0.803.0
```

This is not the first time I get problems with gstreamer and anaconda. This time, it follows a `conda update`. Here are the installed packages for gstreamer under anaconda:

```
$ conda list | grep gst
gst-plugins-base          1.8.0                         0    conda-forge
gstreamer                 1.8.0                         1    conda-forge
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was:

- remove anaconda,
- reinstall it (not the newest version 4.2.0, but version 4.1.0),
- install PyGObject before any other package with:

  ```
  conda install -c pkgw pygobject3=3.18.2
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me https://github.com/conda-forge/gstreamer-feedstock. It uses conda-forge.